# Laravel 5.1 jobs and listeners

Tags: php, laravel

So Laravel 5.1 changes the folders `Commands to Jobs` and `Handlers to Listeners`. What I'm a bit confused about is that the Listeners folder now only handles Events and not Jobs. Are all Jobs self-handling in 5.1? Or should i create a Handlers folder and handle the jobs in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, Jobs are self-handling. They are like Commands and implement the SelfHandling interface. The change is basically just a folder rename so people do not confuse it with other commands (e.g console commands). Try to think of a Job like a Command, since a command is actually performing a job.

Or still, you can create the app/Commands and app/Handlers directory and continue using commands as you are used to. Jobs and Commands are just different ways to do the same thing.